# Navision: How can I hide a group?

Tags: nav

---

I am new with Nav and I would know how to hide field on Page with C/AL code. Finally I read that you only can do it changing it with group.

How can I hide the group. I also was searching it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is that:

http://dynamicsuser.net/nav/f/106/t/31613

I read Only Works with Groups, the global variable you need to créate must be Boolean.